# Sharepoint webpart for conditional formatting?

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know of a Sharepoint webpart that provides conditional formatting?

For example, if I am displaying a table, I would like to be able to change the backcolor of a row if a specific numeric cell exceeds a certain value.

Of course this could easily be done in jQuery, but for political reasons I need to find a way to do it using a webpart.  3rd party commercial solutions are certainly acceptable, and likely preferred.

Comment: For those looking for javascript and non webpart alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424117/how-to-add-a-color-to-a-line-in-sharepoint-2007-list-that-has-a-specific-text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904774/how-to-apply-styles-to-sharepoint-list-based-on-status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the data view web part [2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-data-view-HA010094804.aspx), [2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-data-views-in-sharepoint-designer-HA101631628.aspx) you can get from SharePoint Designer? You can set  conditional formatting properties from there, or if you need more complex formatting you can [edit the xsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300164.aspx) manually.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I'm going to have to shamelessly self-promote. We've got a product coming out soon that does cell and row based conditional highlighting, and may or may not have many other features that I'm not allowed to express any opinion on that aren't directly relevant to this question.

Here's the pre-release post:
[Pentalogic Highlighter](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/03/sharepoint-highlighter-new-product-coming-soon/)

I wouldn't normally post such things, but your requirements are too good a match to not mention it.

Edit: I should officially make note my affiliation with the product: I helped develop it.

Edit edit: Here's the [release post](http://bit.ly/kiOhp3) (since it's now actually a useful answer).